# Oil bath related restrictions

Tags: bath

I read somewhere that applying Basma / Vibhooti after oil bath (abhyangana snana) is not allowed.

Any references to this?

Any other restrictions on daily rituals after oil bath?

Comment: oil bath should not be done on days when you cut hair/nails. it should not be done before sunrise (except on deepavali). oil (on head at least) should be applied by someone else. for men, it should be done on saturday. for women on friday. there may be more but that's all i know

Comment: Thanks. Question was what restrictions are there AFTER oil bath.